# RPC readtime out problem

Tags: solidity, web3.py, pancakeswap

- What I want to do: look through all pairs in pancake V2(currently 1261k pairs), and get token0 and token1 address, thus read their source code through bscscan api, to identify whether its source code has certain specific function.
- How Im doing: Im using [web3.py](https://web3.py), for the setup:

```
web3_utity = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/", request_kwargs={'timeout': 50}))
```

​   for the token0 and token1 address, and Im using 5 threads, each thread has a scan(selfm index) function

```
def scan(self, index):
    pair_addr = self.factory_contract.functions.allPairs(index).call()
            
    pair_contract = self.web3_utity.eth.contract(address=self.web3_utity.toChecksumAddress(pair_addr),
                                                             abi=self.abi_pair)
    token0_addr = pair_contract.functions.token0().call()
    token1_addr = pair_contract.functions.token1().call()
    sleep(0.3 * random.randint(1, 3))
```

- Problem: after a while(usually about 40-50min), errer: requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bsc-dataseed.binance.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10). Re-run the code doesn't solve the connection err.
- Question: Im assuming this is caused by the server rpc node: 'bsc-dataseed.binance.org', anti-scrap. Note that 'bsc-dataseed.binance.org' is binance's public rpc note, if I buy some other rpc node service, connect to those rpcs, will it solve the connection error? If not, what can I do? Im hoping to find a solution which allows me to scan all pairs smoothly and efficiently in pancake V2. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

BSC public endpoint's Rate limit is 10K/5min as stated in [their official documentation](https://docs.bnbchain.org/docs/rpc/#rpc-endpoints-for-bnb-smart-chain). That is more than what you are using in your script(4K/5min). If it has anything to do with rate limiting/scrap detection, it won't happen after sending 40 - 50K requests.

It seems like the BSC server is flooded with too many requests.  It usually happens when the network is congested and the HTTP queue is full. Do the following observations fit your case?

1. When errors occur, there is a very high failure rate(but not 100%) for HTTP requests.
2. The issue resolves by itself after a while.
3. There is no definite time limit for this incident.

If this is the case, you can just wait for a while until the network is less busy.

If you are considering other RPC services, you can try [our BSC node](https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-bnb-smart-chain/). The developer plan is free and it comes with 3 Million free requests every month.